# How can I relate taxonomy terms in drupal with category ids in another db?

Tags: php, oracle, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have a working system running on oracle db. Inside that I have a set of employees under different categories,sub categories etc.,. Now I have to build a system in drupal fetching these data+additionals. I planned to setup the category sub category etc, with the taxonomy and TAC in drupal. I have a set of SP for fetching data from oracle. My question is how can I relate the taxonomy terms with those category ids(Employees are classified under category ids, so I have to keep track of the taxonomy relates to the categories in oracle). I'm new to drupal. Please help me guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a field that stores the corresponding oracle id to the vocabulary in Drupal? That is if you cant name the terms directly so that they match the records in oracle.

I've used the following modules in the past to solve similar tasks. Perhaps they can be of use to you.

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper